# Please Help Me to Identify these seeds whose one end is pointy and other rounded?

Tags: identification, seeds

I bought these seeds with the label of `anise hyssop`  but I don't think that these are of `anise hyssop` because as I go through the internet and various video it just doesn't match.

Seeds Image with size comparison

[image: seeds Image with size comparison]

After sprouting

[image: after sprouting]

After 2 weeks of sprouting

[image: after 2 weeks of sprouting]

Side view

[image: side view]

Right now I tried to look for the plant's stem shape (round or square) but they are not big enough to tell anything with clarity.

But their leaves are reflecting little light like bead blast metal finish.

Maybe the images are not clear as they are taken at night, I will try to take image with better camera quality in day light.

Meanwhile it will be really helpful even indication to family or genus.

Answer (score 1):

So far after going into more internet search I think it is quit close to [**`aster`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aster_(genus)) but still trying to connect it more.  I will update this answer in future with more evidence.